# Filling out a web form automatically with a text file

Tags: java, c#

I request a web page in the browser and I should fill out the text boxes it has. They are too many text boxes and it takes too mush time too fill them and the result of this latency is an expired page. I have written those inputs in a text file (each line for each text box). I want to write a program that when it is running, it fills out the form and I just click the submit button of the website.
The form is something like the following image: 
I have a form which somehow looks like the following image:
[image: form to fill out]

I searched a lot to find a way to fill out the text boxes automatically in `C#` but did not find anything. My question is that is there anyway to set the values of these text boxes in C# and send them back to server?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Selenium is one answer

Comment: This can be done via automation tools more easily.

Comment: @DavidWallace As I have written, How can I fill the web form's text boxes automatically?!

Comment: did you create the web form?

Comment: @RishiGoel actually I myself wanna write a program that does that

Comment: @AlexW no, it is a server side web form and I request that through the internet

Comment: Have you tried AutoFill form browser add on? Like :
Mozilla Firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/
Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en

I never use these add on, but it should be work. For me, I just use LastPass for auto fill form purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's kind of complex.  This is like saying "I want to drive a car".  You haven't really made it clear which parts you are and aren't able to do already, or what it is that you need to know.  If you could ask a more focussed question, and maybe indicate what kind of level you're at with your programming, it might be possible for someone to give you an answer.

Comment: @MohammadAzisFatoni some of its text boxes prevent auto fill ability. I guess they do not let the browser to cache their data.

Comment: @DavidWallace I know programming well enough, Consider that I have a stream of strings and I want to write a .NET or maybe java program that extract these streams and fill the corresponding entries in the web form. But I just need to do that automatically. thanks

Comment: I think it would be better if you could give how your form looks like and how are your text file looks. Which make the question more easier to understand. And also do show what have you tried so that enhancement would help you.

Comment: I would advise looking  into HtmlUnit if you want to do this in Java.

Comment: @DavidWallace Don't you suggest any code or link?!

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Is that OK?!

Comment: Umm, OK.  How about the Getting Started page on the HtmlUnit source forge site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a json object, then a javascript function that iterate that json and figure out by each value the selector of the correct input to use and set the correct value.
Then when the page open, use the dev console.
paste the json object, paste the function.
Run the function and the form should get fill out.
=)